# where is Session's attributes are saved

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tapestry

I'm trying to add an attribute to session, in a huge pre-realized project (web application project using Java and Tapestry framework), but I don't know where the attribute are saved, so that I can declare a new attribute for Session

Comment: why would you need to directly modify the session storage as opposed to accessing it via a Session object?

Comment: [This](http://tapestry.apache.org/session-storage.html) might help.

Comment: @zack6849, I need to add a SessionTime attribute that can be modified under certains events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact , I found out that attributes are added like variable into the session declaration, using just `session.setAttribute("Attribute", name)` 
and then it will be saved, and you can access it using `session.getAttribute(name)`